# How i can change columnSpan onClicked event of MouseArea in qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

This my QML ApplicationWindow :

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    GridLayout {
        id : grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows    : 3
        columns : 3
        property double colMulti : grid.width / grid.columns
        property double rowMulti : grid.height / grid.rows
        function prefWidth(item){
            return colMulti * item.Layout.columnSpan
        }
        function prefHeight(item){
            return rowMulti * item.Layout.rowSpan
        }

      //  model: 9

        Rectangle {
            color : 'red'
            Layout.rowSpan   : 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)

        }
        Rectangle {
            color : 'yellow'
            Layout.rowSpan   : 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)
        }
        Rectangle {

            color : 'green'
            Layout.rowSpan : 1
            Layout.columnSpan : 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)
        }
        Rectangle {
            color : 'red'
            Layout.rowSpan   : 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)

        }
        Rectangle {
            color : 'yellow'
            Layout.rowSpan   : 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)
        }
        Rectangle {

            color : 'green'
            Layout.rowSpan : 1
            Layout.columnSpan : 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)
        }
        Rectangle {
            color : 'red'
            Layout.rowSpan   : 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)

        }
        Rectangle {
            color : 'yellow'
            Layout.rowSpan   : 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)
        }
        Rectangle {

            color : 'green'
            Layout.rowSpan : 1
            Layout.columnSpan : 1
            Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
            Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)
            MouseArea {
             anchors.fill: parent
             onClicked: {

              // how can i change the columnSpan 

             }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How i can change the columnSpan of the last Rectangle onClicked event of the his MouseArea?

In general i want for each Rectangle,when i click on him ,its columnSpan change into 1 or 2 o 3, and the property width of the other two Rectangles in the same row automatically change

before click grid

[image]

after click grid

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution goes something like this:

```
MouseArea {
     anchors.fill: parent
     onClicked: {
         parent.Layout.columnSpan = 3; // or 2 or 1
     }
 }
```

However, the cleaner solution is to define a component in a separate file (`MyGridRect.qml` for example) that contains everything within each of these `Rectangle`s so you aren't duplicating code. Then you can leave the onClicked behavior up to the parent component to decide which objects to collapse/expand. If you were a little more specific in your question about what the behavior should be, it would be easier to give you a code example of how this would work.

Answer (score 0):

First, associate your Rectangle with `id` property, then you can use its `id` property to change its span:

```
 Rectangle {
     id: myrect6    
     color : 'green'
     Layout.rowSpan : 1
     Layout.columnSpan : 1
     Layout.preferredWidth  : grid.prefWidth(this)
     Layout.preferredHeight : grid.prefHeight(this)
     MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked: {
             myrect6.columnSpan : 2
             // how can i change the columnSpan 

         }
     }
```